# Passing Search Result From fragment To Another fragment

Tags: android

I Have Fragment That Do the Search And Get The Result From The Server 
and send the Result To another Fragment withe list view 
To show it . the result it show empty list nothing show
 Fragment Search

```
   public class Search extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText Drugname;
    Button SendDrug;
    private ProgressDialog plog;
    private List<SearchAvailDrug> drugreq= new ArrayList<SearchAvailDrug> () ;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public Search() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        Drugname=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchdrug);
        SendDrug =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.startdrug) ;
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, drugreq);
        SendDrug.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       SendDataUp(Drugname.getText().toString());
    }





    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
    private void SendDataUp(final String Drugname){
        Log.i("SendDataUp","Start");
        String url = Urls.URL_AvailDrug;

        //showing dialog box
        plog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        plog.setIndeterminate(false);
        plog.setMessage("Registration  Please wait ...");
        plog.show();

        // Start Using Volley
        // Request a string response
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        hidePDialog();
                        String UserIdNum=null;
                        Log.v("Search",response);
                        try {
                            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(false)))
                            {
                                hidePDialog();

                                ;


                            }
                            else
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray RideJArray = new JSONArray(response);
                SearchAvailDrug ride = new SearchAvailDrug();                                     ride.setDrugBrand(jpart.getString("BrandName"));                                      ride.setPharmcyNameAr(jpart.getString("phname_ar"));                                        ride.setPharmcyNameEn(jpart.getString("phname_ar"));
        ride.setPhinfo(jpart.getString("info")); ;

                                    ride.setLang(jpart.getDouble("lang"));
                                    ride.setLat(jpart.getDouble("lat"));
                                    drugreq.add(ride);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       Bundle args = new Bundle();
                       args.putParcelableArrayList("mylist", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) drugreq);
                        Fragment fragment = new Listpage();
                        fragment.setArguments(args);
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_nav_main, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();


                        // shownextpage();


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Error handling
                        System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAILED TO CONNECT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("BrandName",Drugname);
                return params;



            }
        };

        // Add the request to the queue
        int socketTimeout = 30000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
    }
    private void shownextpage(){

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Fragment fragment = new Listpage();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_nav_main, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

     private void hidePDialog() {
        if (plog != null) {
            plog.dismiss();
            plog = null;
        }
    }

}
```

and  it show it in the another fragment List view
 and here is the code

```
public class Listpage extends Fragment {
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private List<SearchAvailDrug> drugreq= new ArrayList<SearchAvailDrug>() ;

    public Listpage() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_Listpage_list, container, false);
       Bundle args = getArguments();
        ArrayList<SearchAvailDrug>arrayList;
      // arrayList = (ArrayList<SearchAvailDrug>)args.getParcelableArrayList("mylist");
        drugreq = args.getParcelableArrayList("mylist");
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, drugreq);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listpharmcy);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return  view;
    }

}
```

the problem it show me empty list view 
after i load the fragment

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the "newInstance" recommendation when dealing with Fragments and arguments, otherwise, Android OS might recreate the instance with null arguments.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/6828464